# Tapit "No available creatives"

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm getting the following message with tapit ads (via mediation using admob):

11-28 16:18:41.512: D/TapIt(20993): {"error":"No available creatives"}

Does it mean that there is no Ad to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using AdMob Mediation?

This message is logged by TapIt probably to say it doesn't have an ad. If you're mediating with other networks though, you might get an ad from one of those networks for the same request, so it doesn't necessarily mean AdMob Mediation has no ad to display. If AdMob Mediation can't get an ad from any network you've configured, it'll notify you via the `onFailedToReceiveAd` callback.